# How to use let inside if block inside a do notation in haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement, let

I'm getting an error with the following code:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter parameter"
    parameter <- getLine
    if head parameter == "c" then
        let object = getObject parameter
        print object
    else
        putStrLn "Error, try again"
        main
```

The error I get is:

```
parse error on input `print'
```

when trying to print the object. If I instead try to print the value of the function without saving it with let it works just fine, but I need to save the object for later use.

How should the syntax be to make it work?

Also in the "else" part I get the following error:

```
The function `putStrLn' is applied to two arguments,
    but its type `String -> IO ()' has only one
    In the expression: putStrLn "Error" main
```

It thinks I try to run main as a parameter to putStrLn, but what I really want to do is first show the error and then run main again. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The syntax is `let .. in expr` so you need `let object = getObject parameter in print object`.

Comment: Ah, so simple! I thought "in" was only used outside do notations. Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code.

Firstly, there's the parse error. There's two ways to fix this. One is by using a let .. in block, as @Lee points out.

```
let object = getObject parameter
in  print object
```

Alternatively, we can just start another do block in the else clause:

```
then do
   let object = getObject parameter
   print object
```

Secondly, you're comparing the head of a string, to another string:

`head parameter == "c"`

getLine returns a string, so the head of a string is a character. We can just change this to

`head parameter == 'c'`

And finally, you're trying to do two statements in one block, similar to before in your else clause:

```
else 
    putStrLn "Error, try again"
    main
```

If you want to chain together multiple statements, we have to use a do block, as before:

```
else do
    putStrLn "Error, try again"
    main
```

Putting it all together:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter parameter"
    parameter <- getLine
    if head parameter == 'c' then do
        let object = getObject parameter
        print object
    else do
        putStrLn "Error, try again"
        main
```

Comment: Ops! I made a small simplification to make it easier to read the code. The parameter was split up into a list of string with "words", so the head identifies the command. Thanks though! Everything works perfectly now!

Comment: @SebastianPaulsen Ah ok, I thought that might have been a typo. Happy to help!

Comment: If I want to use the "object" later in the code and run functions on it, how would I do it? I can't access object outside the if statement, and I can't make a "global" variable in the beginning of main since variables can't be changed. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: @SebastianPaulsen You can either use the state monad or something similar, or you can try and structure your program to only do the work in the if statement. Also, because of laziness you could assign it outside the if statement, and it will only be evaluated if you use it later on.